# SimpleXML user agent

Tags: php

I am trying to pull in an RSS feed using simpleXML in PHP.

The rss website says if you do not have a correct user agent you will get blocked.

How do I set the user agent?

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a `user_agent` setting that you can set (in a temporary way) using :

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'user_agent_goes_here');
```

It's also in your `php.ini` (if you change it from here, it will be permanent)

Example :

```
//Setting the user agent as Firefox 9.0
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0');
$xml = file_get_contents($rssfeed);
$simplexml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Comment: If you change it in your `php.ini` it will be permanent, otherwise, no. from the manual : "`ini_set()` Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending. "

Comment: Interesting find, now how does one make a request that would actually use this? I tried this it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cUrl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to retrieve the feed and then use the [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) function to create the DOM from the string which contains the content. Using cUrl, you can set the user agent you want in this way:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
$dom = simplexml_load_string($content);
```

And you can get a good example and a full code here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php#93163

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with [cURL](http://php.net/curl) using the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` argument.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/rss.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); //$user_agent would contain your agent.
$xml = curl_exec($ch); //xml stored in the variable $xml
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short?  You send a user-agent header.

The long answer is that you will need to use one of PHP's methods of fetching content over HTTP (probably curl) to initiate the connection, send the expected header and pull down the XML file you are trying to access as a string.  Once you've done this, parse the retrieved data with the XML parser of your choice.

For example, to get Curl to pose as IE 6:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/6.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
```